# AJAX respond with status 200! But return to error part , even repose is in JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I'm calling sub domain controller method from main domain using ajax call as follows

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://demo.trufin.in/getBorrowerType",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            //success part
        },
        error:function(error){
        //error part
        }
    });
```

I get response as 200 (Status ok) as well as I get json data as follows

```
[{
    "borrowerTypeName": "Co-operative Member",
    "addedDate": "2016-10-04",
    "borrowerTypeId": 1,
    "addedBy": "23646",
    "isActive": 1
}, {
    "borrowerTypeName": "Bank Account Holder",
    "addedDate": "2016-10-04",
    "borrowerTypeId": 2,
    "addedBy": "23646",
    "isActive": 1
}, {
    "borrowerTypeName": "Others",
    "addedDate": "2016-10-04",
    "borrowerTypeId": 3,
    "addedBy": "23646",
    "isActive": 1
}]
```

But problem is ajax returns to error!!

Tried with all possible solutions like

```
dataType:jsonp
cross origin
```

But didn't work.

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: Ajax returns to error part instead of success part!

Comment: Check the console. Are you getting a warning saying something like 'No Access Control headers present'?

Comment: The thing I find suspect about your ajax call is that you're doing a POST without passing any data.

Comment: Oh! and, BTW, why the `java` tag?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No! I'm not getting any error in console

Comment: Then you need to debug the arguments returned to the `error` handler in order to diagnose the problem. We can't help you given the small amount of information you've shown us

Comment: @MauricePerry tried with data, as well as GET method

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee that the json the server is returning is invalid for one reason or another. There's no other way you'd be getting sent to error with a 200 statuscode. The json you've presented is valid, so i assume you've just not copied the whole response. That or you're mis-interpreting results and the 200 status code is on a preflight request, and the followup is not 200.

Answer (score -1):

For consistency's sake, try wrapping your numbers also in quotation marks.